# Invalid object name 'my table name' asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have uploaded a site with database on smarterasp.net Hosting
and I have created RSS page for the site but when I try to access this page this error appears:

```
Invalid object name 'tblRSS'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name ' 
tblRSS'.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'tblRSS'.]
```

my code is :

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL7002.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_?????????;User Id=?????????_admin;Password=???????????;")

    Using (conn)
        Dim ad As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblRSS", conn)
        ad.Fill(dt)
    End Using
```

I'm sure the tblRSS table exists, can you help me?

Comment: use SQL management studio to log in with the same account...and try to select the table

Comment: Are you so sure..? That error very much suggestsit does not; or at least does not in the instance and database the application has connected to.